# Android activity as Dialog: Doesn't display layout content properly

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I have an `DialogActivity` with an `EditText` and a `Button`. Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight2">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColorHint = "@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable"
        android:hint="Contact ID"
        android:padding="15dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/input_username"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/elevation"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Add Contact"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity in manifest :

```
<activity android:name=".AddContactActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="Add Contact"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
</activity>
```

What my Activity looks like :

[image: Dialog Activity]

Problem is that activity contents of layout are overlapping. What I need is the height of the dialog should wrap the contents of `Activity`.

Any help would be great !! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` from the `EditText`. The final layout should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="Contact ID"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/input_username"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Add Contact"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And adding android:padding="30dp" in RelativeLayout, solved my problem. Accepting this as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know that helped!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove attributes `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` from your `EditText`.

**Update your dialog layout as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight2">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColorHint = "@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable"
        android:hint="Contact ID"
        android:padding="15dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/input_username"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/elevation"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Add Contact"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: yup ! exactly..!

Comment: If my answer helps please mark it as accepted answer and give an upvote. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sure ! I have up voted, but my reputation is low. Up vote my question may it helps.